# Что происходит при перемещении экземпляров класса в вектор (С++)

Tags: c++, классы, vector, конструктор

Уважаемые Гуру, объясните, какие процессы происходят при исполнении этого кода. Почему так много конструкторов вызывается? Т.е. при добавлении элемента в хвост каждый раз происходит копирование каждого элемента. А если тысячи их?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Test
{
    int var;
public:
    explicit Test(int arg) : var{arg}
    { cout << "explicit Test(int arg) var=" << var << endl; }

    Test(Test &arg) : var{arg.var}
    { cout << "Test(Test &arg) var=" << var << endl; }

    Test(Test &&arg)
    { 
      swap(var, arg.var);
      cout << "Test(Test &&arg) var=" << var << endl; 
    }

    virtual ~Test()
    { cout << "virtual ~Test() var=" << var << endl; }

    void test_proc() noexcept
    { cout << "test_proc() var=" << var << endl; }
};


int main()
{
    vector<Test> vt;

    vt.emplace_back(Test(1));
    vt.emplace_back(Test(2));
    vt.emplace_back(Test(3));
}
```

Вывод:

```
explicit Test(int arg) var=1
Test(Test &&arg) var=1
virtual ~Test() var=0
explicit Test(int arg) var=2
Test(Test &&arg) var=2
Test(Test &&arg) var=1
virtual ~Test() var=0
virtual ~Test() var=0
explicit Test(int arg) var=3
Test(Test &&arg) var=3
Test(Test &&arg) var=1
Test(Test &&arg) var=2
virtual ~Test() var=0
virtual ~Test() var=0
virtual ~Test() var=0
virtual ~Test() var=1
virtual ~Test() var=2
virtual ~Test() var=3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всем нужно пользоваться правильно...

```
vector<Test> vt;
vt.reserve(4);

vt.emplace_back(1);
vt.emplace_back(2);
vt.emplace_back(3);
```

и вы получаете

```
explicit Test(int arg) var=1
explicit Test(int arg) var=2
explicit Test(int arg) var=3
virtual ~Test() var=1
virtual ~Test() var=2
virtual ~Test() var=3
```

Вам все еще пояснять, почему ваш код работает так, как работает?...

Comment: Спасибо. Если не сложно, поясните.

Comment: У вас совершенно напрасно создается для каждого `emplace_back` свой экземпляр `Test` - 3 штуки. Который потом копируется в вектор (`emplace_back` вызывает конструктор для переданных аргументов сам) - еще 3 конструктора. Ну, и при перераспределении памяти в векторе при добавлении новых элементов (место ведь заранее не выделено) - копирование в новое местоположение в памяти. Итого от 6 (если все же место выделено заранее) до 9 (если все плохо) конструкторов. У вас их как раз 9. Я выделил место заранее (`reserve`) и в `emplace_back` передаю просто аргумент конструктора...

Comment: В общем, эта функция меняет вместимость вектора (capacity), резервируя память под необходимое кол-во элементов. Благодарю за объяснения. Кому интересна тема - ссылка на справочник http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/reserve/

Comment: Да, а что не так?

Comment: Все так. Тема раскрыта.

Comment: Тогда закрывайте вопрос - птичка слева от ответа означает, что он принят...